# Uploading images form-data in .net api on CentOS 7

Tags: .net, linux, image, service

I’m working with friends on a project for students association and we need to publish this. We use server VPS with CentOS7 and reverse proxy on Apache. In the project we have few endpoints with taking images in form-data and we save them in wwwroot folder. When I connect with server by ssh and I run api by command `“dotnet Targi.API.dll --urls http://*:5000”`, a all functionality is working without any errors until I disconnect ssh in PuTTy. To longer lifecycle api I copied this service for linux:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/vhosts/domena.pl/httpdocs
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/vhosts/domena.pl/httpdocs/Targi.API.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=apache
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Our website is working, we get all jsons but when uploading images by multipart/form-data we get HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. So all is working correctly without Form Data posts and we have no idea why.

I don’t have experience in the linux system so I am asking you for any hints and suggestions.
Greetings, Peter